# Windows Local Magento Installation Elastic Search Unknown 503 error from Elasticsearch null

Tags: elasticsearch, xampp, windows-10, magento2, local

Installed Magento 2.45 in windows 10 local setup. From the admin panel i do see Catalog Search index notification.
Actually the notification says "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running." but its Windows 10. Did some search online and tried to use reindex commands

[MagentoAdminPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1URfo.png)

```
C:\M\xampp8.1\htdocs\magento2>php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
**Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
Unknown 503 error from Elasticsearch null**
```

and Even i got his error when i am trying to install Sample database for Magento

I had two directories of Elastic search earlier, i deleted one and used the existing one for installing Magento.

Elastic search running well on localhost:9200 as supposed to be.

Do see these warning in elastic search running cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Npk.png)

Please help how to solve this issue with Elastic Search.

tried to reindex and deleted the old directory of elastic search but still getting 503 unexpected error

found from elastic search logs

```
path: /_alias/magento2_product_1, params: {name=magento2_product_1}
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) [elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
[2022-12-29T13:14:58,517][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [] master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires two nodes with ids [9vMxUNvOQe6K-uF-beID0Q, o0-gGk_2SquCXSYgS7n9WA], have only discovered non-quorum
```

Also tried the following setting in elasticsearch.yml with all other values default
discovery.seed_hosts: false
also no use and commented.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with other forum member advise  and what i observed from the logs and going through Elasticsearch documents. From the AppData\local\temp\elasticsearch and geoipdirectories i do see two folders and see the same relevant data from the Elasticsearch logs.. i stopped alll Magento Apache services, deleted Elasticsearch directory and also all data from AppData\local\temp\elasticsearch. Extracted the Elasticsearch zip file to the same Magento installation directory as before.. started Elastic Search bat file (this time the log is different and created a new folders in AppData and started.. started Magento services and all went good.